# Delete button is in another layout, how to call it from another layout

Tags: android

I've got 2 tabs with custom listview. I want to implement delete function, but the delete button is placed in tabs holder, so I cannot call this button from tab fragment

[TabLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTOGO.png)

[Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq55Q.png)

[Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFKnz.png)

Comment: Use interface or broadcastreceiver or eventbus to get button click callback into your fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your delete button is in another layout then you probably inflate that layout which has the delete button and get the button then perform the function...

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sport_, container, false); // replace fragment_sport_ layout by layout which has delete button..
Button mdelete= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delt_button); // wirte your own Id at place of delt_button...
mdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to this in your fragment:

```
    Button fab = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.del);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Insert your delete code
        }
    });
```

Also please supply me with your code so i can give you exact code to your answer.

Comment: Tnx for your answer, but this code is nont for my situation

Comment: @IlyasKassym can you give me your activity code so i can show you how to do it

Comment: @IlyasKassym i need your Fragment code and TabLayout code, you can put it on google drive if it does not allow you to post it here